# Count occurrence of unique variables

Tags: r, count, statistics

I have a data frame of variables, some occur more than once, e.g.:
    a, b, b, b, c, c, d, e, f
I would then like to get an output (in two columns) like this:
    a 1; b 3; c 2; d 1; e 1; f 1.
Bonus question: I'd like the variable to be named something (e.g. 'other' if less than 2 occurrences) if the variable is appearing less than 'n' times in the counted column.

Comment: Use `as.data.frame(table(yourvector))`.  If `a`, `b`, `c` are the repeated column names. Replace `yourvector` with `colnames(yourdata)`

Comment: Bonus tip: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RichardScriven As reproducibility goes, to me this is no worse than other cases I have seen, like pasting some lines of a csv or results printed by R's console. @ everyone: The bonus question isn't a dupe that I know of (?), so downvotes simply for lack of formatting seem a bit harsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tabulating and collapsing**

Your example vector is

```
vec <- letters[c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6)]
```

To get a tabulation, use

```
tab <- table(vec)
```

To collapse infrequent items (say, with counts below two), use

```
res <- c(tab[tab>=2],other=sum(tab[tab<2]))
# b     c other 
# 3     2     4
```

---

**Displaying in two columns**

```
resdf <- data.frame(count=res)
#       count
# b         3
# c         2
# other     4
```

Technically, the "first column" here is the row labels, accessible with `rownames(resdf)`.

Similar options include:

- `stack(res)` for two actual columns
- `data.frame(count=sort(res,decreasing=TRUE))` to sort

In all of these, `tab` or `c(tab)` can be used in place of `res`.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for pointing that out; I'd missed it. I've added some base R options that strike me as simpler.